# PHP/MySQL: What is returned when no matches are found?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to use PHP to find out if no matches are found. I tried the following, but "is_resource()" always returns true.

```
$result = mysql_query('...');
if(is_resource($result)){
// Results are found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_num_rows()` will do the trick.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    //Results are found
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

So $result will always be a  resource as long as you have proper access to the database. And mysql_num_rows() assumes that the query itself ran successfully. I'd say try something like this:

```
if($result === FALSE) // Query failed due to not having proper permissions on the table
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
else if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0)) // We have more than 1 row returned which means we have data
    // INPUT RESULTS PROCESSING HERE
else // No rows were returned therefore there were no matches
    echo 'No rows returned';
```

Hope that helps a little =)
Look here for more information if you need: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want: [mysql_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

If the query fails it mysql_query will return false so you can check your code like this:

```
if ( $stmt = mysql_query("...") )
{
    // Do some things
}
else
{
    // Do some other things
}
```

Or you could use mysql_num_rows like the people above have stated.
But you should really be looking into [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) it's a built in database class. Learn it and use it. Your life will be so much easier.